# Matlab parfor, cannot run "due to the way P is used"

Tags: performance, matlab

I have a quite time consuming task that I perform in a for loop. Each iteration is completely independent from the others so I figured out to use the `parfor` loop and benefit from the i7 core of my machine.

The serial loop is:

```
 for i=1 : size(datacoord,1)

    %P matrix: person_number x z or
    P(i,1) = datacoord(i,1); %pn
    P(i,4) = datacoord(i,5); %or
    P(i,3) = predict(Barea2, datacoord(i,4)); %distance (z)

    dist = round(P(i,3)); %round the distance to get how many cells
    x = ceil(datacoord(i,2) / (im_w / ncell(1,dist)));
    P(i,2) = pos(dist, x); %x

end
```

Reading around about the parfor, the only doubt it had is that i use dist and x as indexes which are calculated inside the loop, i heard that this could be a problem.
The error I get from matlab is about the way P matrix is used though. How is it? If i remember correcly from my parallel computing courses and I interpret correcly the parfor documentation, this should work by just switching the `for` with the `parfor`.

Any input would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is `P` preallocated? I believe `parfor` doesn't like variables which change size/shape.

Comment: If you provide code that compiles as is, with maybe some example or rand data, that makes it much easier to diagnose.

Comment: Yes, P is preallocated, the exact error is: "In a PARFOR loop, P is indexed in different ways, potentially causing dependencies between iterations".
As for some data, `datacoord` is a (:,5) matrix with `(int, int, int, int, int)` matrix, since the problem persists even if you leave the first 2 lines of the loop I wouldn't go further with the data since it gets quite messy expecially with the predict thing..

Comment: Can you confirm what `im_w`, `ncell` and `pos` are - variables? I'm guessing the `predict` part is the one that's taking a long time - in that case you ought to be able to take a lot of the other stuff out of the loop and just do the `predict` part via `parfor`.

Comment: Try replacing "P(i,3) = predict..." with a simpler one for testing, like "P(i,3) = datacoord(i,4);". If it works fine now, then the problem is with the way you are using state-space model inside PARFOR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, in a PARFOR loop, 'sliced' variables such as you'd like `P` to be cannot be indexed in multiple different ways. The simplest solution is to build up a single row, and then make a single assignment into `P`, like this:

```
parfor i=1 : size(datacoord,1)

    %P matrix: person_number x z or
    P_tmp    = NaN(1, 4);
    P_tmp(1) = datacoord(i,1); %pn
    P_tmp(4) = datacoord(i,5); %or
    P_tmp(3) = predict(Barea2, datacoord(i,4)); %distance (z)

    dist = round(P_tmp(3)); %round the distance to get how many cells
    x = ceil(datacoord(i,2) / (im_w / ncell(1,dist)));
    P_tmp(2) = pos(dist, x); %x
    P(i, :) = P_tmp;
end
```

Comment: Ok, this fixed the problem and now the code runs (i had to create a "sliceable" version of Barea2 as @Divarak suggested in his comment since it caused problems. What i don't get is why even in the parfor the loop is executed sequentially? It takes the exact amount of time of the for version and putting a print in it shows clearly that it executes sequentially (the only noticeable change is the order, it starts from the last one and goes up)

Comment: If you're using R2013a or earlier, you need to explicitly open a pool of workers using the `matlabpool` command before running a PARFOR loop. In R2013b and later, the pool opens automatically for you (unless you've disabled it).

Comment: Yep, i'm using R2012b so I guess it's time to update :) Thanks!